# How to find C or C++ code leaks using Instruments (Leaks) - Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

```
int* foo = new int[10];
foo = NULL;
sleep(60);
```

Instrument is not finding any leak in above code, how do I use Instrument tool to find C or C++ code leaks. I have stack overflowed most of the explanation is based on objective C codes...

Comment: Are you sure the compiler hasn't *optimized-out* the `new` call?  Try using `foo` (writing and reading it) and see what happens.

Comment: OK, show the modified code that actually *uses* `foo`.

Comment: @trojanfoe You are right, I think its internally optimized, When I tried to set and get values, it showing leak in instrument. Please put this as your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that compiler will optimize out the call to `new` in the following code fragment:

```
int* foo = new int[10];
foo = NULL;
sleep(60);
```

as it's smart enough to know that it's not being used.  If you add code to use `foo` then compiler won't do this and you should see the leak you are expecting:

```
int* foo = new int[10];

foo[3] = 23;
foo[8] = 45;

printf("%d %d\n", foo[3], foo[8]);

foo = NULL;
sleep(60);
```