# Xcode 7.2 & Instruments memory leak not working for c++ code

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-leaks

I use the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int* foo = new int[10];
    foo = nullptr;
    sleep(60);
}
```

I build it inside XCode 7.2 and run instruments to see memory leak.
I changed time delay differently and changed Instruments checking delay (from 10 to 2 sec). I tried to build project differently (Release, Debug) and also I tried to avoid compiler optimization:

```
int* foo = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    foo[i] = i*3 + i^2;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    cout << foo[i] << endl;;
}
foo = nullptr;
sleep(60);
```

but I still can't see any leak inside Instruments/leak bars. 
What I do wrong?

Upd: I found a workaround, if I stop my console app at breakpoint and then, from the console, run

```
MacBook-Pro-andrey-2:~ owl$ leaks Ctrain
Process:         Ctrain [30305]
Path:            /Users/owl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ctrain-cuhszmbcsswlznetmyijwykgudlz/Build/Products/Debug/Ctrain
Load Address:    0x100000000
Identifier:      Ctrain
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  debugserver [30306]

Date/Time:       2015-12-23 21:30:28.768 +0300
Launch Time:     2015-12-23 21:30:25.837 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/leaks
Analysis Tool Version:  Xcode 7.2 (7C68)
----

leaks Report Version:  2.0
Process 30305: 390 nodes malloced for 34 KB
Process 30305: 1 leak for 48 total leaked bytes.
Leak: 0x1001054f0  size=48  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x10006e000
    0x00000002 0x00000006 0x0000000a 0x0000000e     ................
    0x00000012 0x00000016 0x0000001a 0x0000001e     ................
    0x00000022 0x00000026 0x93554c2c 0x00007fff     "...&...,LU.....
```

but it is just workaround and not the answer why Instruments can't catch this leak (or any leak in my case).

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122617/memory-leak-checking-using-instruments-on-mac)?

Comment: thanks for comment, but I already tried that too=( with function call and { } block

Comment: yes, I saw that post. my time delay interval is greater than Instruments delay

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a memory leak as you will never be able to delete the memory but you will not be able to observe it unless you redo the operation.  If you had

```
int main()
{
    int* foo;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        foo = new int[10];
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

You would be able to observer the memory being consumed by the process increasing as we never release the memory we request before grabbing more memory.

Comment: Sounds strange, because I need to detect one mem leak, but I've got no mem leak with Your example neither. Maybe I need to set some settings for c++ in Instruments or something else?

Comment: Why I will never be able to observe this leak? I can do it with crt marcos for MSVC..

Comment: Since compiler is to smart and removes dummy code: `foo = new int[10];` :).
You have to use this block of memory. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14811858/1387438